# sameAs Schema.org markup for multiple social media accounts

Tags: schema.org, markup

What is the best way to use the Schema.org sameAs markup when the company manages more than one social media account on the same platform, i.e. has individual Twitter accounts: 1) the main account; 2) customer services / help and support account; 3) careers account.

Additionally, if the website that's being marked-up has subdomains (again, for careers, Customer Service etc.) - should they all be marked-up using the full list of accounts, or the corresponding account only?

Comment: Do you ask about Google’s [Social Profile Links](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/social-profile-links), or about Schema.org in general?

Comment: Social profile links, sorry the question lacked clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You're allowed to use multiple social accounts for same organization, Google may pick only one. but it make sense to keep it separate. It means I prefer to use corresponding account for subdomains.

For your main website you can use your main social website profile.

For your service.subdomain.com, you can use your company service profile.

I don't know why you're doing that, sites like amazon have dedicated solution for customer service, they did not have separate Facebook or Twitter pages for that. I mean really, you will provide help service through your twitter/facebook account. There are so many web solution out there that is dedicated for that. And for carrier it does not totally make sense to create a separate social account for that. But as I said you're allowed to use more than one social accounts for schema. You can also use corresponding accounts for subdomain which is also my top choice.